# Can't open file in Documents directory Swift

Tags: swift, directory, nsfilemanager

I am trying to load a file from my applications documents directory using the following code, however, I am getting the error `The folder “Documents” doesn’t exist.`. Am I doing something wrong?

```
let paths =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
var documentsUrl = paths[0]
do {
    let fileURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentsUrl.absoluteString)
    print(fileURLs)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Change `.absoluteString` to `.path` Or use `contentsOfDirectory(at: URL)` and pass the url

Comment: I see, thank you, that does allow me to see the contents. When I try to open a file using `MLModel.compileModel(at:)` I get the error `The file “model.mlmodel” couldn’t be opened.`

Comment: Feel free to open a new question and tag it accordingly.

Comment: Sure thing, thank you